# IntelliJ cucumber .ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, cucumber

I don't know if this question has been asked/answered yet. If so, I'm sorry. But I'm new to IntelliJ and there's a lot of foreign words I yet need to understand.

My problem is as follows:
I installed the complete IntelliJ package, created a new Java project and created a new class inside my src folder:

```
package de.itsme.hello;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

So I try to run it and I get this Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

I tried adding cucumber-core:4.0.1 to the project's dependencies but then I got another exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
at cucumber.runtime.BackendModuleBackendSupplier.get(BackendModuleBackendSupplier.java:39)
at cucumber.runner.SingletonRunnerSupplier.createRunner(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:38)
at cucumber.runner.SingletonRunnerSupplier.get(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:32)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:75)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

I don't need cucumber or at least not for now. Is there a way to make it either work or remove it from the project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot of your Run configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have the packet JDK installed incorrectly and this produces you an error. Or maybe your classspath is incorrect.